# Finding the growth rate of averages over several years by level in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame in r that has a column for "low", "mid", and "high" and a column for year (either 2019, 2020, or 2021) with averages following. I want to find growth rates for the separate levels over the three years (ex. growth rate of the low plots from 2019-2021). Is there a way to do this without creating a new data frame?

Data frame:

| level | year | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low | 2019 | 1300 |
| Low | 2020 | 2966 |
| Low | 2021 | 4049 |
| Mid | 2019 | 2065 |
| Mid | 2020 | 4723 |
| Mid | 2021 | 5915 |
| High | 2019 | 2194 |
| High | 2020 | 4827 |
| High | 2021 | 5978 |

Comment: welcome to SO. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data looks like and what your preferred output would look like? Based on what you've put in your question it seems like you are just looking for 3 numbers.

Comment: I added the data frame im looking at, and I'd like 2 numbers for each level, a growth rate from 2019 to 2020 and a growth rate from 2020 to 2021, so a total of six numbers

Comment: Seems like your output will probably reside in a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can `group_by()` level and use `lag()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(level) %>% arrange(year) %>% mutate(growth_rate = avarage / lag(avarage))
```

Comment: Then why not `arrange(year)` before `mutate()`?

Comment: I could do that, @Greg. I just figured it was not necessary because the data provided was already sorted. But I agree sorting would be more consistent. Edited as suggested